# Select Cyrillic Address on "Latin1_General_CI_AS" Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, collation

I have addresses in cyrillic stored correctly (with `nvarchar`) in the `slq-server`database.

When selecting the row where the cyrillic address is, the select statement returns the row correctly.

BUT when trying to select all the rows with a specific address (e.g. in a `where` clause) the select finds nothing, because it takes the cyrillic search term, converts it according to the latin collation into `?????'` and searches for `?????'` in the database, which it of course can't find.

Can that be fixed e.g. via a server or database setting, without requiring the prefixed `"N"` and without loosing all the german, french,... accents?

And/Or is there an "overall collation" for westeuropean AND cyrillic symbols, or a 16 Bit collation for UNICODE in general?

Comment: Where do you execute your T-SQL statement - in SQL Server Management Studio, with some script, ... ? Thanks.

Comment: This is normally a **client** setting. For instance, when I connect from PHP I have to set the `CharacterSet` connection option to `UTF-8`.

Comment: How and where is the statement created and how and where is it executed? Are you calling this from some kind of application? Something like `WHERE SomeColumn='SomeCyrillic'` cannot work. This will be interpreted as *extended ASCII* string, while `WHERE SomeColumn=N'SomeCyrillic'` would use the string as `UCS-2` (almost the same as `utf-16`), thus keeping all your special characters.

Comment: Btw: In most cases it's recommended to use typed parameters instead of literals... (read about *little bobby tables*)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the collation of your existing database and column per this link? It might help us answer your question: [View Collation Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/view-collation-information?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass your searching string in `cyrillic`, but without using `Unicode`, you should launch your query within a context of "cyrillic database", i.e. if your db (I name it `LatinDB`) has `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation you should create another database, say `CyrDB`, that has a Cyrillic collation, and then query your db from the context of `CyrDB` like this:

```
use CyrDB;

select *
from LatinDB.dbo.your_tbl
where address = 'какой-то там адрес' -- here I'm not using Unicode, no N character behind my string
```

> Can that be fixed e.g. via a server or database setting, without
>   requiring the prefixed "N" and without loosing all the german,
>   french,... accents?

If you mean conserving these "accents" in the resultset, they will be conserved as the field is `nvarchar`.

If you mean that you want to enter the query within the same `Cyrillic` context, you should precise what symbols you think to loose, if their ascii codes are from 1 to 127 you can still use `CyrDB` to launch your query, but if your characters are above 128 and you don't want to pass them as `Unicode`, you should use the context of another db with appropriate collation

Comment: This might work in very small environments, but I doubt this would work with bigger databases. And then you might need to add a lot of DBs, if there are more languages in use. All of them must be synchronised somehow. Seems to be a rather inefficient approach...

Comment: >>>This might work in very small environments<<<In normal environments **Unicode is used to pass Unicode strings**. The question was if Unicode could be passed as ascii, and the only possible solution is to do it within a database that has appropriate collation

Comment: No , the correct approach is a typed parameter. Literal values are dangerous and difficult to handle...